# How do I get my site to show up through github?

Tags: github, github-pages

I uploaded my files to github, checked off readme, commit changes, selected masterbranch, and I got the following message as I scrolled down the page:   Your site is published at https://tanishav842.github.io/Recipes/ but there is nothing there except for the word Recipes, which appears at the end of the site address that had been established for me through github.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is it supposed show? Is it a static webpage or a web app ?

Comment: It's probably because your repository does not contain any valid HTML. (It also seems that it's a React app, hence you'll have to deploy it to your repository either under a `docs` subfolder, on the `master` branch, or on the `gh-pages` branch.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Tani, to have your own page hosted by [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com) it need to be stored in one of the following places

- In a public repository named `<your-github-username>.github.io`
- Under a `docs` folder in `master` branch of any public repository you own
- In `gh-pages` branch of any public repository you own

---

It means your [Recipes repository](https://github.com/TanishaV842/Recipes) are pretty much there.

Just copy your `master` branch content to a new branch named `gh-pages` and push it:

```
git checkout -b gh-pages
git push -u origin gh-pages
```

In addiction, as [commented Edric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61180838/how-do-i-get-my-site-to-show-up-through-github#comment108247592_61180838), it would be cool to have your pretty nice stuff added to your page.

By now, I suppose GitHub is using your `README.md` that just have the word *Recipes* there!

---

Anyways, [Here](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages) you can find a bunch of details about **Working with GitHub Pages** and also some step-by-step tutorials to learn how to do it properly

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Ok, so my repository is there?  I just need to copy my content gh-pages?  Those are some helpful details artu-hnrq.  I will certainly give a try and review the tutorial.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hosting a site is better supported by the GitHub application. Try following these steps to see if they help:

1. Download either GitHub for Mac or GitHub for Windows, depending on your operating system. Open the app and log in using the account you just created.
2. (On Mac): After you login, click advanced and make sure that your name and email are correct. Then, click "Install Command Line Tools", just in case you want to start using the command line later in life.
3. Create a new repository in your GitHub application. Name it your-username.github.io. The name is very important. Note the folder that GitHub is saving the repository to. Make sure the "Push to GitHub?" box is checked.
4. Move your website's files into the folder that GitHub just created when you made the repository. IMPORTANT: Your homepage HTML file must be called "index.html", and it must exist in the top-level directory.
5. Back in the GitHub application, you should see your files in the left column. Make sure they are all checked. If so, enter a message in the text box called "commit summary", something like "initial commit." Then, click the commit button.
6. Click the "Publish repo" button in the top right corner.
7. Give it about 10 minutes, then check your-username.github.io. Your website should be there!

Here's the reference link:
https://gist.github.com/TylerFisher/6127328

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: You should've noticed that the original poster of the GitHub Gist has issued an update that the Gist was from 2013 and is now "out of date", as well as linked to the [GitHub documentation](https://pages.github.com/).